# без итеративные хелперы для std vector

Tags: c++, ооп, visual-c++, stl, операторы

Думаю над реализаций 2 кастомных функции для массива: all(...) - сравнивает весь массив с примитивным типом например float, либо массивом этого-же типа, операторы <, <=, >, >=, !=, ==. Так-же any(...) сравнивает если попадётся в массиве идентичное число или какое-то из чисел последовательности содержится в массиве над которым сравниваем .

Пример псевдокода:

```
std::vector< SomeType > valuesArray = GetSomeValues(); // какие-то входные данные
std::vector< SomeType > desiredVals = { 3, 9, 7.5 };   // какой-то массив 

 // пример синтаксиса
if ( all( valuesArray, <,  20.0 ) ) {
    // посмотрим все ли числа массива < 20
   //  потом посмотрим есть ли там хоть 1 число из массива desiredVals 
   // и если да, глянем есть ли все ли они больше 2.35
    if( any( valuesArray, ==, desiredVals ) && all( values, >, 2.35 ) )
         fire(1);
} else if ( all( valuesArray, >=, 5.1 ) && any( values, <=, 8 ) {
         fire(2);
} else 
  fire(0)
```

Так-же думаю, что если массив содержит экземпляры класса, наверное можно переопределить оператор присвоения, оператор bool для if случаев, и оператор Primitive ( ) будущий возвращать какой-то из примитивных членов класса для сравнения с примитивами, присвоение думается переопределить, чтобы можно было создавать дубликат массива с значениями, нечто вроде ранжирование, вроде такой похожий функционал был в std::range, но за пяток лет подзабыл что там нового вышло в stl?

Пример псевдокода:
    std::vector< SomeType > selection1 = any( valuesArray, >=, 15 ); // создаст копию всего что больше или равно 15 без повторений
    std::vector< SomeType > selection2 = all( valuesArray, ==, 0.5 ); // создаст копию всего что равняется 0.5 с повторениями

Вопрос такой, если не прибегать к громоздкому коду с итераторами и циклами как было принято брутфорсить такие кейсы в 2000х, есть ли какой-то способ не изобретая велосипед, штатными средствами шаблонов в c++ 11 и stl максимально коротко реализовать такого плана синтаксический функционал?

Comment: Вопрос должен быть закрыт, так как на [Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) вопросы принято задавать только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь [Stack Overflow на английском](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Ну с таким синтаксисом вы явно не сделаете, потому что не сможете передать оператор как аргумент (если только макрос не возьмете). Есть вариант сделать в духе `all(вектор) >= 42`. Еще есть вариант закодировать оператор в название: `all_greater_eq`, или что-то такое. Остальное реализуется в лоб.

Answer (score 2):

Это можно сделать довольно просто с использованием `std::valarray`:

```
#include <valarray>
#include <iostream>
#include <ios>

int main() {
    const std::valarray values{3., 9., 7.5};

    std::cout << std::boolalpha
              << "All  < 20.  : " << ((values < 20.).min() == true)  << '\n'
              << "All  < 9.   : " << ((values < 9.).min() == true)   << '\n'
              << "Any >= 5.1. : " << ((values >= 5.1).max() == true) << '\n'
              << "Any >= 10.  : " << ((values >= 10.).max() == true) << '\n';
}
```

Вывод:

```
All  < 20.  : true

All  < 9.   : false

Any >= 5.1. : true

Any >= 10.  : false
```

Comment: Пример работает, начиная с С++17. А с C++11/14 не прокатывает. Ну и наверно хорошим правилом было бы явно обозначить `return 0`.

Comment: @Majestio вопрос задан в 18 году (почти 19), а ответ дан в 20 :). Почему это является хорошим правилом?

Comment: Ничего не имею против, я плюсанул есличё)

Comment: Ну раз функция возвращает значение, нагляднее указывать что именно она возвращает, ИМХО

Comment: @Majestio в принципе я согласен, что в реальном коде надо указывать это явно. Удивительно, но однажды это даже создало мне проблемы (грязные хаки с переименованием `main`-а и в итоге функция без `return`). Но для примера на стеке стараюсь минимальный код давать https://stackoverflow.com/a/25476560/13970074